# object properties in python

Tags: python

```
   class test:
      a="hi"

      def msg(self):
          print the variable for which the object is referring to

   t= test()
    print t.b
```

From the above code is there any way to tell that the object is referring to a variable b which does not exist

Comment: well,you get `AttribuiteError` if you refer a variable which does not  exist.

Comment: "it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `__getattr__` method, see [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__):

```
In [1]: class test(object):
   ...:     a = 'hi'
   ...:     def __getattr__(self, val):
   ...:         print 'you are accessing ', val
   ...:         
   ...:         

In [2]: t = test()

In [3]: t.b
you are accessing  b

In [4]: t.c
you are accessing  c

In [5]: t.a
Out[5]: 'hi'
```

EDIT:

```
class test(object):
    a = 'hi'

    def msg(self, var, default='undefined'):
        setattr(self, var, default)
        return default

    def __getattr__(self, val):
        print 'attribute %s not found, setting..' % val
        return self.msg(val)


>>> t = test()
>>> print t.a
'hi'
>>> print t.b
'attribute b not found, setting..'
'undefined'
>>> t.b = 'this is black magic'
>>> # notice no message is printed here about attribute not found
>>> print t.b
'this is black magic'
```

EDIT2:

```
>>> d = {'a': '1'}
>>> d.setdefault('b', 'b')
'b'
>>> d
{'a': '1', 'b': 'b'}
>>> d.setdefault('a', 'b')
'1'
>>> d
{'a': '1', 'b': 'b'}
```

Comment: In the statement hasattr(t, 'b') instead of hard coding b cant we get the variable from the object itself

Comment: Or how will the object know that the variable b is being reffered

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean? In your question, you asked how to check if the object is referring to a variable b which does not exist. @Cameron's answer shows you how to catch an exception. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: So in my class i need to print that the object is referring to a variable which does not exist..Please see the edit in the question

Comment: Can __getattr__(self, val) print 'you are accessing ', val be defined in msg() some how.So i can access it in msg function

Comment: What is the problem that you're trying to solve? I'll update my answer for you, but I think, what you're trying to do would be classified as a 'code smell'

Comment: Why would you implement __getattr__ properties? Why not invoke __msg()__ from the ____getattr()____ method?

Comment: I will just give u a brief description of what i am doing,I am getting a variable from db snd if this variable doest not exist i just need to return the same variable as sting from msg function.Thanks for all the help

Comment: How are you getting this variable from the database? How are you checking if it doesn't exist? What is invoking the message function? Update your question, please.

Comment: Can you answer my question? How are you getting this variable from the database? How are you checking if it doesn't exist? What is invoking the msg() function?

Comment: Its a db query,it would stored in a variable say in a dictionary as d.update({'a' : 1}).If the variable exist only the dictionary would be updated.then i can dict['key'] will give mt the value as 1.But if there are no results from the query i need to update the passed string into dictionary as d.update({'passedstring':passed string}).So now when i say dict['key'] will give me passed string.Hope i am very clear.The element exist or not is being done in the msg func from an if loop using if somevar.count() > 0:

Comment: Sounds like you want to use dict.get()

Comment: How doest dict.get() be relevant to my example

Comment: You tried explaining, but I'm sorry I just do not understand what you want to do. I'll pass on this question.

Comment: Please dont be sorry,U have helped a lot..may be my implementation should be done in some other way..I was just asking if the key is not found in the dictionary what ever the key the object is looking for should be updated in the dictionary

Comment: Rajeev, what you're looking for is dict.setdefault. I'll update my answer.

Comment: yes exactly but how do u do it in the object notation i.e, default should be obj.requestedvalue

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You will get a `NameError` on the `print b` line, and an AttributeError on the `print t.b` line.

You can catch these exceptions like this:

```
try:
    print t.b
except AttributeError as e:    # or `except AttributeError, e` on Python < 2.6
    # Do something...
```

Comment: How will the object know that its being  referred to a variable which does not exist

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
class tester(object):
    a = 'hi'

    def __getattr__(self, val):
        print 'accessing attribute %s failed!' % val

>>> t = tester()
>>> t.a
'hi'
>>> t.b
accessing attribute b failed!
>>>
```

EDIT: Removed some redundant code

Comment: That is replicating the standard behavior. What good is that?

Comment: Good call. I didn't realise that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If that's *all* the code, then of course there is no `b`.  But, I assume that you want us to assume there could be more code.  If there is, or perhaps if this code is imported as a module by other code, then there is no way to tell until it is run.

Answer (score 0):

All members of an object are stored in that objects `__dir__`. So you can just do this:

```
>>> "msg" in dir(t)
True
>>> "b" in dir(t)
False
```

This works for the standard case, and may behave differently if descriptors are involved, or `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` are overloaded.

Comment: The first line is not correct, as you say yourself in the last line.  `__dir__` is a way for an object to report the attributes it *wants* you to know about.